# How can I print a newline without flushing the buffer in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print out lots of large walls of text in quick succession.
They're supposed to be frames.
At the moment it looks like this:
[image]

I believe this is caused by line buffering by default in python, though since I'm unsure, I've attached this gif.

Is there a way to make sure that the terminal will print the whole block as one big unit, rather than as a bunch of lines?

```py
screen_1 = Screen(#...

for xpos in range(-150, 150):
    v0.move(xpos, -30) # move vertice
    for edge in edges: edge.show() # show all edges
    screen_1.printscr() # print screen
    screen_1.clearscr() # clear screen
```

The key here is the `printscr()` function which just prints out:

```py
class Screen:
    #...

    def printscr(self):

        print(self.frame)
```

the frame will be a big wall of characters separated by newlines. Some variation on:

```py
self.frame = (" " * pixelWidth * xPixels + "\n") * yPixels
```

`pixelWidth`, `xPixels` and `yPixels` are all just integer variables

Comment: You haven't shown your code. Without a [mcve] you're just asking us to evaluate your own hypothesis without giving us any ability to create our own

Comment: You can't just print frames one after the other. You'll be throttled by the scrolling behavior of the terminal. All terminals are like this. One possible fix is to send commands to clear the screen and re-home the cursor at the top-left of the window before each frame. This will hopefully prevent the scrolling, but you'll get flicker. Another is double-buffering: Print the whole screen for a frame to an internal buffer, then home the cursor (without clearing) and print the buffer. However, you might see tearing. There's no 100% answer, sorry.